# Htaccess for custom URL

Tags: .htaccess, modx-revolution

I have URL site.com/page/ and have htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But my CMS need for the search URL without slug, like site.com/search?query=

How to write the rule for custom URL?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Can you clarify with more examples?

Comment: We use CMS Modx. All of our URL are like site.com/page/ with slug in the end of path. Our SEO-manager make the rule in htaccess (look at code before). But also we use the plugin "search", and its need to URL without / slug (search?query=). In other way it doesn`t work. I need the custom rule in htaccess for one page SEARCH without "/" after /search/

Answer (score 0):

You can make a rule to ignore `/search` URI:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^search/?$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```